# creating same type of objects based on a condition from an existing object ; C# LINQ

Tags: linq, object, collections

I am trying to breakdown an object into more than one object of same type based on a condition. How can I write a LINQ query in C# for this.

```
public class Order
{
   public List<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}


Order co = new Order();
```

Say for example my **co** object has 14 drivers and 12 vehicles.

I want to create objects of type Order which will contain 5 drivers and 4 vehicles.

```
if (co.Drivers.count > 5 || co.vehicles.count > 4)
       {

          //Break the total number of Drivers and Vehicles into sets of 5 and 4 and add them to the Orde object.


       }
```

Thanks
BB

Comment: Not enough information. What happens if you have 10 drivers and 2 vehicles? Does the first order get 5 drivers and 2 vehicles, and the second one get 5 drivers and 0 vehicles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var newOrders = new List<Order>();
for (int drivers = 0, vehicles = 0; 
     drivers < co.Drivers.Count || vehicles < co.Vehicles.Count; 
     drivers += 5, vehicles += 4)
{
    newOrders.Add(new Order { 
            Drivers = co.Drivers.Skip(drivers).Take(5), 
            Vehicles = co.Vehicles.Skip(vehicles).Take(4)
    }));
}
```

Comment: Mahesh Thank you. After breaking down into groups of 5 drivers and 4 vehicles I am bulding an XML for each order. But I want to maintain the sequence. For ex : DriverID for the driver1 in the first group is 1, drvier2 is 2,..... driver5 is 5. Now for the first driver in the second XML the ID should be 6 not 1. How can I maintain the sequence of the drivers. Thanks BB

Comment: @BB: You mean that drivers and vehicles have ids and you need to order them based on those ids when populating into new orders?

Comment: No they don't have Id's. Say the original Order has 15 drivers. When I break it down my newOrders will have three orders now. The index for the first driver in the second order of newOrders will be 1 but I want it as 6. similarily the index for the first driver in the third order of newOrders will be 1 but i want it as 11.

Comment: Do you have this index stored in a variable? If you are talking about inherent index provided by the list, it wouldn't be recommended, as u need probably need to store 5 empty drivers to get your index to 6 in the second order. I could give you a solution once I understand what you are asking for.